# iOS objective c How to load next coming video while playing current video without delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

In my application ai have loaded all video url's to AVPlayer and it has previous and next buttons here i have setup player

```
    -(void)setUpMyNewPlayer
    {
            [self addTimer];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:_videosArray[0]];
        _currentIndex =0;
        videoPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]init]; //WithPlayerItem:_avPlayerItem];
        videoPlayer.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = NO;
        AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
        [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"playable"] completionHandler:^{

            AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
            videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
            AVPlayerLayer  *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:videoPlayer];
            playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize;
            playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.playView.frame.size.width, self.playView.frame.size.height);
            [self.playView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
            [videoPlayer play];
            CMTime interval = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.5, NSEC_PER_SEC);
            dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();


            __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
            [videoPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval
                                                      queue:mainQueue
                                                 usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {
                                                     // Use weak reference to self
                                                     if (_currentIndex==_contentImages.count-1) {
                                                         weakSelf.nextButton.hidden=YES;
                                                         weakSelf.previousButton.hidden=NO;
                                                     }
                                                     else if (_currentIndex==0)
                                                     {
                                                         weakSelf.previousButton.hidden=YES;
                                                         if (_contentImages.count>1) {
                                                             weakSelf.nextButton.hidden=NO;
                                                         }
                                                         else
                                                         {
                                                             weakSelf.nextButton.hidden=YES;
                                                         }

                                                     }
                                                     else if (_currentIndex>0 && _currentIndex!=_contentImages.count-1)
                                                     {
                                                         // NSLog(@"Showing Both");
                                                         weakSelf.nextButton.hidden=NO;
                                                         weakSelf.previousButton.hidden=NO;
                                                     }

                                                 }];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying1:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:item];
        }];

    }

-(void)itemDidFinishPlaying1:(NSNotification *) notification {
   //  
    // Will be called when AVPlayer finishes playing playerItem
    if (_currentIndex == _videosArray.count-1) {

    }
    else{

        _currentIndex = _currentIndex+1;
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:_videosArray[_currentIndex]];
        AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
        AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
        [videoPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
        [self changePage:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward];
        [self addTimer];
    }

}


-(void)addTimer
{
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1 target: self
                                             selector: @selector(callAfterOneSecond1:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}

-(void) callAfterOneSecond1:(NSTimer*)t
{
    [[AppDelegate shared] showLoading];
    if (videoPlayer.rate !=0 && videoPlayer.error == nil && videoPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        [[AppDelegate shared]removeLoading];
        [myTimer invalidate];
        myTimer=nil;
    }

}
```

## pragma mark- PreviousAction

```
- (IBAction)previousButtonAction:(id)sender {

    if (_currentIndex == 0) {

    }
    else{
        _currentIndex = _currentIndex-1;
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:_videosArray[_currentIndex]];
        AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
        AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
        [videoPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
        [videoPlayer play];
        [self changePage:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse];
        [self addTimer];
    }
   }
```

## pragma mark- NextAction

```
- (IBAction)nextButtonAction:(id)sender {  

    if (_currentIndex == _videosArray.count-1) {

    }
    else{
        _currentIndex = _currentIndex+1;
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:_videosArray[_currentIndex]];
        AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
        AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
        [videoPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
        [videoPlayer play];
        [self changePage:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward];
           [self addTimer];
    }
}
```

Here the player is playing well but with small delay. . How to load next coming video while playing current video without delay.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit rusty and the iOS documentation on the whole of AVFoundation is woefully inadequate if you want to do anything slightly complicated. Its been a while since I did this but something like this should work (I'm assuming you have an `NSArray*`, `pAssets` containing all your videos as `AVAsset*`)

```
// Define the composition.
AVMutableComposition*       pComposition        = [AVMutableComposition composition];

// Define the tracks in the composition.
AVMutableCompositionTrack*  pCompositionVideoTrack  = [pComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID: 1];
AVMutableCompositionTrack*  pCompositionAudioTrack  = [pComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID: 2];

CMTime time = kCMTimeZero;
for ( AVAsset* pAssetsAsset in pAssets )
{
    // Grab first video and audio tracks
    AVAssetTrack*   pAssetsAssetVideoTrack  = [pAssetsAsset tracksWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo].firstObject;     
    AVAssetTrack*   pAssetsAssetAudioTrack  = [pAssetsAsset tracksWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio].firstObject;

    // Get time range of entire video.
    CMTimeRange     timeRange   = CMTimeRangeMake( kCMTimeZero, timepAssetsAsset.duration );

    // Insert the entire video and audio into their respective tracks at "time".
    NSError*    pVideoError     = nil;
    NSError*    pAudioError     = nil;
    [pCompositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange: timeRange ofTrack: pAssetsAssetVideoTrack atTime: time error: &pVideoError];       
    [pCompositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange: timeRange ofTrack: pAssetsAssetAudioTrack atTime: time error: &pAudioError];

    // Move time along appropriately.
    time    = CMTimeAdd( time, pAssetsAsset.duration );
}
```

If you then pass the `AVMutableComposition` is derived from `AVAsset` so you can use this as normal and drop it into an `AVPlayer` (via an `AVPlayerItem`).

Now you can seek to any point in the video.  Store the start/finish points of each video and you can easily seek to it.

**Edit**: Its ultra simple to use AVPlayer.   First you need to create an AVPlayerItem .. and then you need to play it.

```
AVPlayerItem*   pPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: pComposition];
AVPlayer*   pPlayer     = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem: pPlayerItem];
```

Now you need to attach it to a view's layer.  So from inside your ViewController do something like this:

```
AVPlayerLayer*  pLayer      = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer: pPlayer];
[self.view.layer addSublayer: pLayer];
```

Comment: Hi Goz as i new to AVPlayer will you please provide me an example  on this.

Comment: Hi Goz you have initialized pAVComposition and not used in the above code. . and initialized a player item with pComposition from where i have add that will you please help me in detail.

Comment: Its giving error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AVPlayerItem tracksWithMediaType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000001a2e0'

Comment: Yes, sorry.  pAVComposition should have been pComposition.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AVQueuePlayer` instead of simple `AVPlayer`. At the end of current video it will preload next video.

See how to use `AVQueuePlayer` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22785665/1271424

Comment: Ok brother i will try and let you know. . .

Comment: AVQueuePlayer does not buffer video items.

Comment: You also can't seek backward and forward properly with an AVQueuePlayer ...